# fwrite(-ing) a list into a txt.file

Tags: c, fwrite

I made a function which turns the random boxes(/nodes/links) of a `list` **into an** `array`(consecutive-memory). All of this because I am trying to `fwrite` this `list` into a `file(.txt)`.

But all that I see when I open the file is the words from the `value` field and then 39 spaces either blank or with a random character or whatever else. Can someone tell me why this happens?

How can I get the result, either only the `value` field of each array element (`list` link) or all 3 but by calling fwrite once?

```
struct box {
    char value[20] ;
    struct box * next ; 
    int occurs;
} ;

typedef struct box Box;
typedef Box * List;


Box* list_toarray(List mylist){
    List iter=mylist;
    Box *packed;
    Box *dup;
    dup=packed=malloc((sizeof(Box))*lenlist(mylist));
    while(iter!=NULL){
        memcpy(packed,iter,sizeof(Box));
        packed++;//packed[1];
        iter=iter->next;
        if(iter!=NULL)
            (packed-1)->next=packed;
        else
            (packed-1)->next=NULL;
    }
    printf("\nInput list to array(Consecutive blocks of memory) :\n");
    report(dup);
    return dup;
}

void fread_fwrite_lsttoarray(Box *dup){
    FILE *myfile;
    myfile=fopen("fwfr.txt","wt");
    fwrite(dup,sizeof(Box),6,myfile);
    fclose(myfile);
}
```

Also this is how I call the `function`:

```
fread_fwrite_lsttoarray(list_toarray(newlistasc));
```

where `newlistasc` is a random `list` with `struct box` elements

Comment: Your data is binary and not textual. So you see only the readable part of it when you "open" your file.

Comment: How can i print only the readable part and discard all others(by calling fwrite once)?

Comment: Print only the `value` field? Like in `dup->value`. You will have to iterate the list for that

Comment: hm sounds ok to me.I'leave this post for a bit more see if anything new pops.thanks.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Also if i fread the file will i get the same list?I mean will there be  a next value on the `next` field?

Comment: You should decide what you want to use this data for first.

Comment: What do you mean?Let me rephrase that.Will i get the next node if i refer to it though the memory i fread to?

Comment: This file will only save the text from your nodes. If you want to preserve metadata, you better to give up on the text format and save the whole list in binary.

Comment: So i open i binary file and forget the good printing of the text?

Comment: On the other hand, the pointer values would be pretty useless to save, as these will have no meaning on a different run of the program. But you certainly can deduce the list ordering by the order of the text fields.But you will have to add the printing of `occurs` as the answer is suggesting.

Comment: regarding: `packed++;//packed[1];`  'packed' is a pointer, not an instance of a struct box.  So this will only step through memory the length of a pointer (depending on the underlying architecture, 4 or 8 bytes

Comment: the pointer `iter` is not defined, nor initialized in the posted code

Comment: pointers in files are meaningless.

Comment: `dup` is a well known C library function,  Using the same name of a local variable as is already used for a C library function is a very poor programming practice

Comment: when calling C library functions ( for instance, `fopen()` `fwrite()`, etc.  always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: there is a call to `malloc()`, but not corresponding call to `free()`

Comment: the list of data already exists, so why create it again?  Just reference the original data

Answer (score 1):

in function fread_fwrite_lsttoarray()

change

```
fwrite(dup,sizeof(Box),6,myfile);
```

to

```
fprintf(myfile, "%s, %d\n", dup->value, dup->occurs);
```

Do not write elememt next into file, because it's value is meanless outside memory.

Comment: while i was edititng i missed it(fixed it now).also i want fwite to be the function to do it not fprintf

Comment: i did this while(dup){
  fwrite(dup,sizeof(dup->value),1,myfile);
  dup=dup->next;
 } but prints the words with gaps . how can i eliminate them?

Comment: @xprt fprintf is the best choice, because you opened the file in text mode. fwrite works well in binary mode.

Comment: @xprt try: while(dup){ fwrite(dup,strlen(dup->value),1,myfile); fputc('\n',myfile); dup=dup->next; }